# GraphQL mutation with JSON in android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, graphql

I am trying to write a GraphQL mutation which contains a JSON parameter.

```
signup( firstName: String! lastName: String tel: String location: JSON email: String! gender: Gender nic: String! userType: UserType isActive: Boolean password: String! )
```

I Create a JSON object and parse it into sever.

```
val location  = JSONObject()
location.put("latitude","1.232")
location.put("longitude","1.34234")
```

But it gives errors

```
 Reason: 'location' Not valid JSON (line 1, column 11):\nmutation ($data: UserCreateInput!)
```

All other parameters(String and enum) are correct. I Checked it.

Comment: Can you share the GraphQL schema for that mutation as well as the `UserCreateInput` type?

Comment: signup(
firstName: String!
lastName: String
tel: String
location: JSON
email: String!
gender: Gender
nic: String!
userType: UserType
isActive: Boolean
password: String!
): AuthPayload

Comment: I am, personally, stil not clear. There is no `latitude` and `longitude` in this structure. Plus, not everybody checks comments for question details, please add further information by editing question body: After all, this increases the odds of receiving a proper answer :)

Comment: In mutation, we have to provide JSON, In that JSON contains the location details. That's why create a JSON object and parse it into mutation. Just like firstName:"some_name" , Location: above josn. Am I doing the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

What I am guessing is going on is this:

Someone on your team has created a custom Scalar `JSON` with a corresponding coercing. Your GraphQL request variable `location` should most likely be a string that that gets parsed to json at your server level.

The fact that the error says "location" is not a valid JSON means that your actual GraphQL request variable is coming through like this:

```
{
 "variables": "{"location": "\"location\": {\"latitude\": 12.34, \"longitude\": 12.34}",
 ...rest
}
```

GraphQL will pass a value `"\"location\": {\"latitude\": 12.34, \"longitude\": 12.34}"` to your custom json parser, which is not a valid json